# How to find repeating sequence of Integers in an array of Integers?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

How to find repeating sequence of Integers in an array of Integers?

00 would be repeating, so would 123123, but 01234593623 would not be.

I have an idea to how to do this, but it is blurry in my mind, and my implementation doesn't go far due to this.

My idea was

1. Offset by a certain amount each time going through a for loop
2. Loop through inside of that and compare chunks of numbers by that offset

In Java, I got this far:

```
    String[] p1 = new String[nDigitGroup];
    String[] p2 = new String[nDigitGroup];

    for (int pos = 0; pos < number.length - 1; pos++)
    {
        System.out.println("HERE: " + pos + (nDigitGroup - 1));
        int arrayCounter = -1;

        for (int n = pos; n < pos + nDigitGroup ; n++)
        {
            System.out.printf("\nPOS: %d\nN: %d\n", pos, n);
            arrayCounter++;
            p1[arrayCounter] = number[n];

            System.out.println(p1[arrayCounter]);
        }

        pos += nDigitGroup;
        arrayCounter = -1;

        System.out.println("SWITCHING");

        for (int n = pos; n < pos + nDigitGroup ; n++)
        {
            System.out.printf("\nPOS: %d\nN: %d\n", pos, n);
            arrayCounter++;
            p2[arrayCounter] = number[n];

            System.out.println(p2[arrayCounter]);
        }

        if (p1[0].equals(p2[0]) && p1[1].equals(p2[1])) System.out.println("MATCHING");
    }
```

When ran with these arguments:

```
        repeatingSeqOf(2, new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "7" });
```

I am correctly filling the section arrays, but it breaks on an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Break it down: first write a function to check if the string is a repeating sequence of n digits. Then loop through the possible values of n.

Comment: Is each integer in the array in the range 0-9?

Comment: Then I think it would be simpler to look at it as a `String`. You could make one out of the array by doing `java.util.Arrays.toString(ints).replaceAll("^[0-9]", "")` or the like. Then, you could compare chunks of the string to each other, starting with substrings one character long and ending with substrings `n/2` characters long, where n = the number of integers.

Comment: do you want to find all the repeating sequences or just the sequence with maximum length or if you just need to know if at all there's repeating sequence of integers in a given string ? 3 different things :)

Comment: I just need to know if any section repeats or not. No need to identify which sections repeat.

Comment: Is the repeating sequence is always a prefix of the whole string?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I am having trouble even doing that, which I did try for quite a while after you suggested it. I just can't grasp the concepts. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MiljenMikic answer's is great, especially since the grammar isn't actually regular. :D

If you want to do it on an array in general, or want to understand it, this does pretty much exactly what the regex does:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3}; // 2, 3 repeats at position 2.

    // for every position in the array:
    for (int startPos = 0; startPos < arr.length; startPos++) {
        // check if there is a repeating sequence here:

        // check every sequence length which is lower or equal to half the
        // remaining array length: (this is important, otherwise we'll go out of bounds)
        for (int sequenceLength = 1; sequenceLength <= (arr.length - startPos) / 2; sequenceLength++) {

            // check if the sequences of length sequenceLength which start
            // at startPos and (startPos + sequenceLength (the one
            // immediately following it)) are equal:
            boolean sequencesAreEqual = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
                if (arr[startPos + i] != arr[startPos + sequenceLength + i]) {
                    sequencesAreEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sequencesAreEqual) {
                System.out.println("Found repeating sequence at pos " + startPos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Strings, remember to use `equals` instead of `==`. Also, you can replace the innermost for loop with `List arrList = Arrays.asList(arr); boolean sequencesAreEqual = arrList.subList(startPos, sequenceLength).equals(arrList.subList(startPos + sequenceLength, sequenceLength);`

Comment: I like both answers, but this answer gives me far more insight into how it actually works, which is what I need. I upvoted both answers, but chose this one.

Answer (score 3):

You can always play with regular expressions to achieve a desired result. Use the [regex backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) and combine it with the greedy quantifier:

```
    void printRepeating(String arrayOfInt)
    {
        String regex = "(\\d+)\\1";
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(arrayOfInt);           
        while (matcher.find())                              
        {               
            System.out.println("Repeated substring: " + matcher.group(1));
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by @AdrianLeonhard is perfectly working. But if I have a sequence of 
**0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 7, 8**
many might be wondering on how to get all the repeated numbers from the array.

So, I wrote this simple logic which prints all the repeated numbers with their positions

```
    int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 7, 8};

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                System.out.println("Number: "+arr[i]+" found repeating at position: "+i+" , repeated at position "+j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string lookIn = "99123998877665544123"; 
// above has length of 20 (in positions 0 through 19)
int patternLength = 3;
// want to search each triple of letters 0-2, 1-3, 2-4 ... 17-19
//   however since there must be 3 chars after the 3-char pattern
//   we only want to search the triples up to 14-16 (20 - 3*2)
for (int i=0; i <= lookIn.Length - patternLength * 2; i++) {
   string lookingFor = lookIn.Substring(i, patternLength);
   // start looking at the pos after the pattern
   int iFoundPos = lookIn.IndexOf(lookingFor, i + patternLength);
   if (iFoundPos > -1) {
      string msg = "Found pattern '" + lookingFor 
                 + "' at position " + i 
                 + " recurs at position " + iFoundPos;
   }
}
// of course, you will want to validate that patternLength is less than
//   or equal to half the length of lookIn.Length, etc.
```

EDIT: improved and converted to javascript (from C# ... oops, sorry about that...)

```
function testfn() {
   var lookIn = "99123998877665544123"; 
   // above has length of 20 (in positions 0 through 19)
   var patternLength_Min = 2;
   var patternLength_Max = 5;
   if (patternLength_Max > (lookIn.length / 2) 
                || patternLength_Max < patternLength_Min
                || patternLength_Min < 1) {
      alert('Invalid lengths.')
   }
   var msg = "";
   for (var pLen = patternLength_Min; pLen <= patternLength_Max; pLen++)  {
      for (var i = 0; i <= lookIn.length - pLen * 2; i++) {
         var lookingFor = lookIn.substring(i, i + pLen);
         // start looking at the pos after the pattern
         var iFoundPos = lookIn.indexOf(lookingFor, i + pLen);
         if (iFoundPos > -1) {
            msg = msg + "Found '" + lookingFor 
                       + "' at pos=" + i 
                       + " recurs at pos=" + iFoundPos + "\n";
            ;
         }
      }
   }
   alert(msg);
}
```

The message box displays the following:

```
Found '99' at pos=0 recurs at pos=5
Found '12' at pos=2 recurs at pos=17
Found '23' at pos=3 recurs at pos=18
Found '123' at pos=2 recurs at pos=17
```

Comment: Does this only do up to patterns of three length? Because it also should match stuff like 123412341234.  Also this gives a out of bounds exception on run.

Comment: No, simply set "int patternLength = 3;" to any number. If you want, put the whole code loop I gave inside a loop for (int patternLength = 3; patternLength < 7; patternLength++) { my code }. This loop would look for every pattern of size 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. Change the 3 and 7 to anything. Remember that you should not use a patternLength greater than half the length of the string you are searching because it would make no sense. For instance looking for a repeating 10 character string inside an eleven character string is nonsense. The string has to be 20 or more characters long for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I ran it in C#....not java...where it ran fine. Really sorry. I have added the java code as an edit. I tested it.

Comment: but this is not the problem he is asking for. you have to get the repeating sequence. Your program is finding the occurrence of string of given length in given string.