# Sorting Order and Finding repeating patterns

Tags: java, arrays

```
      //other arrays sequences sample
      {23,45,38, 9,43,25,18}
      {21,33,22, 5, 1,44,16}
      {28,24, 5,42,15,49,41}
      {43,18,50,29,22,32,25}
      {33,38,27,35,25, 1,12}
      {21,33,22, 5, 1,44,16}
      {28,24, 5,42,15,49,41}
```

I have a little project where i have a list of sequences and i would like to have them rearranged from small to large and reprinted for use to find repeating sequences and show how many time each sequence repeats

Now I wrote a small code sorting the sequences from small to large with the aid of a friend in order to solve the first problem.

But I would like it to work with multiple sets and arrange each set and print them on there own line, In order for me to find the repeating patterns

Yet every time i change the {int} to accommodate more sequences the code fails

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x[] = {37, 36, 20, 23, 44, 27, 24};

        for (int y = 0; y <= x.length; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z <= x.length - 2; z++) {
                if (x[z] > x[z + 1]) {

                    int temp = 0;
                    temp = x[z];

                    x[z] = x[z + 1];
                    x[z + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
            System.out.print(x[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

as part of the second problem finding the repeating sequence i'm looking into dis post and busy reworking to see if it will work.

Yet as far as i see it will find the repeating number and not sequence witch is where i'm stuck.

[How to find repeating sequence of Integers in an array of Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847164/how-to-find-repeating-sequence-of-integers-in-an-array-of-integers)

I'm still new to java and any aid will be appreciated
Kind Regards
Deon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hage, It's small but I learned a lot Here is the working code

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] seq={{ 42, 22, 40, 1, 11, 5, 43 },
                         { 13, 11, 18, 45, 3, 44, 19 },
                         { 46, 1, 32, 47, 35, 7, 36 },
                         { 48, 21, 38, 29, 3, 12, 11 },
            };

            for (int i=0; i < seq.length; i++) {
                int[] x=seq[i];

                Arrays.sort(x);
                for (int number : x) {
                        System.out.print(number  + " ");}
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/ link to some nice breakdown of Arrays

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you split this in two separate questions. 
I will now try to answer to the sorting problem, however, I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem here.

You implemented the [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You can see in the linked Wikipedia article how this is correctly implemented. Basically there is a `do-while` loop as the outer loop.

Alternatively, you could also use Java's [`Arrays#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-)

**EDIT**

You can create a two dimensional array for your sequences like this:

```
  int[][] seq = {
      {23,45,38, 9,43,25,18},
      {21,33,22, 5, 1,44,16},
      {28,24, 5,42,15,49,41},
      {43,18,50,29,22,32,25},
      {33,38,27,35,25, 1,12},
      {21,33,22, 5, 1,44,16},
      {28,24, 5,42,15,49,41}
  };
```

Then, you can iterate over `seq` and sort each contained array individually:

```
for(int i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
  int[] x = seq[i];
  // sort x
}
```

Comment: thanks ill look into the written articles, would like to know how do you define multiple sets of sequences in to a single int for sorting

Comment: define multiple sets of sequences in to a single int for sorting example                     " int x[] = {37,36,20,23,44,27,24}, {37,23,45,38,9,18}; " ore                         
" int x[] = {(37,36,20,23,44,27,24), (37,23,45,38,9,18)}; "

Comment: thanks Hage and Yoseph. Here is the simplified version now to make it work with multple int values in a single pass.                                                                   import java.util.Arrays;

        public class Main {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int x[] = {37,36,20,23,44,27,24};
                Arrays.sort(x,y);
                for (int number : x) {
                    System.out.print(number);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks Hage i have seen dis method on the two dimensional array pop up in my google search results wile trying to find a solution but when ever i try to use it I get dis error " java: '}' expected " on the first container array and " Java: not a statement " on second container array. and so on Now just to Voice i'm still new to dis and finding solutions on every error does take me a little time thanks for the answers and guidance.

Comment: Thanks Hage i got it working with the two dimensional array and sorting with Arrays.sort(x) like Yosept mentioned. how will i get it to print container inparts as of now it prints one long string with all the arrays sorted

Comment: its printing "9182325384345151621223344" and i would like it to print Like dis   9182325384345    with the next sequence on new line 151621223344

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot the commas in the array definition. Two print the sorted arrays on a new line, how about adding newline ? See `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use Arrays.sort(x) to sort the arrays in to order.

Comment: This is not a definitive answer and cannot be put in the answer section