# SVGPath to SVGPath using stroke-dasharray

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to turn SVGPaths containing patterns (for example dashed lines) into SVGPaths using the stroke-dasharray Attribute instead?

```
<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '0, 0, 20, 20' version = '1.1'>
    <!-- What I have -->
    <path stroke = 'red' d = 'm1 1v.1m0 .05v.1m0 .05v.1m0 .05v.1m0 .05v.1'></path>

    <!-- What I want to have -->
    <path stroke = 'green' stroke-dasharray = '0.1 0.05' d = 'm5 1v.75' />
</svg>
```

For example those paths:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lrz8btsz/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="21.6cm" height="27.9cm" viewBox="0 0 2159 2794" version="1.1">
    <g id="0" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000">
        <path data-h="200" d="M1299.63 598.81L1304.32 598.81M1317.05 598.81L1317.15 598.81M1329.72 598.81L1329.82 598.81M1342.39 598.81L1342.49 598.81M1355.07 598.81L1355.17 598.81M1367.74 598.81L1367.84 598.81M1380.42 598.81L1380.52 598.81M1393.09 598.81L1393.19 598.81M1405.77 598.81L1405.87 598.81M1418.44 598.81L1418.54 598.81M1431.12 598.81L1431.22 598.81M1443.79 598.81L1443.89 598.81M1456.47 598.81L1456.57 598.81M1469.14 598.81L1469.24 598.81M1481.82 598.81L1481.92 598.81M1494.49 598.81L1494.59 598.81M1507.17 598.81L1507.27 598.81M1519.84 598.81L1519.94 598.81M1532.52 598.81L1532.62 598.81M1545.19 598.81L1545.29 598.81M1557.87 598.81L1557.97 598.81M1570.54 598.81L1570.64 598.81M1583.22 598.81L1583.32 598.81M1595.89 598.81L1595.99 598.81M1608.56 598.81L1608.66 598.81M1621.24 598.81L1621.34 598.81M1633.91 598.81L1634.01 598.81M1646.59 598.81L1646.69 598.81M1659.26 598.81L1659.36 598.81M1671.94 598.81L1672.04 598.81M1684.61 598.81L1684.71 598.81M1697.29 598.81L1697.39 598.81M1698.88 587.73L1698.98 587.73M1698.88 575.06L1698.98 575.06M1698.88 562.38L1698.98 562.38M1698.88 549.71L1698.98 549.71M1698.88 537.03L1698.98 537.03M1698.88 524.36L1698.98 524.36M1698.88 511.68L1698.98 511.68M1698.88 499.01L1698.98 499.01M1698.88 486.33L1698.98 486.33M1698.88 473.66L1698.98 473.66M1698.88 460.98L1698.98 460.98M1698.88 448.31L1698.98 448.31M1698.88 435.63L1698.98 435.63M1698.88 422.96L1698.98 422.96M1698.88 410.28L1698.98 410.28M1700.48 399.21L1700.58 399.21M1713.16 399.21L1713.26 399.21M1725.83 399.21L1725.93 399.21M1738.51 399.21L1738.61 399.21M1751.18 399.21L1751.28 399.21M1763.86 399.21L1763.96 399.21M1776.53 399.21L1776.63 399.21M1789.2 399.21L1789.3 399.21M1801.88 399.21L1801.98 399.21M1814.55 399.21L1814.65 399.21M1827.23 399.21L1827.33 399.21M1839.9 399.21L1840 399.21M1852.58 399.21L1852.68 399.21M1865.25 399.21L1865.35 399.21M1877.93 399.21L1878.03 399.21M1890.6 399.21L1890.7 399.21M1903.28 399.21L1903.38 399.21M1915.95 399.21L1916.05 399.21M1928.63 399.21L1928.73 399.21M1941.3 399.21L1941.4 399.21M1953.98 399.21L1954.08 399.21M1966.65 399.21L1966.75 399.21M1979.33 399.21L1979.43 399.21M1992 399.21L1992.1 399.21M2004.68 399.21L2004.78 399.21M2017.35 399.21L2017.45 399.21M2030.03 399.21L2030.13 399.21M2042.7 399.21L2042.8 399.21M2055.38 399.21L2055.48 399.21M2068.05 399.21L2068.15 399.21M2080.72 399.21L2080.82 399.21M2093.35 399.21L2098.04 399.21" fill="none" stroke="#000000" />
        <path data-h="344F6" d="m412.49 1126.76h.06m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.1m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.1m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.1m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.1m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.1m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.1m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.09m.05 0h.09m.04 0h.07"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I learnt how to find all points of the path and all the distances between them, yet I have no idea how to find the longest pattern in that.

```
    //REM: Simplified version of code for test purposes
    //REM: Might require a SVGPath.getPathData() polyfill (https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js/)
    //REM: Returns a list of absolute coordinates from the path segments
    //e:=<path>
    function _toAbsoluteList(e){
        var tA = [];

        if(e && e.getPathData){
            for(var tL=e.getPathData(), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
                var tS = tL[i];

                switch(tS.type){
                    case 'M':
                        tA.push(tS.values);
                        break
                    case 'L':
                        tA.push(tS.values);
                        break
                    case 'l': case 'm':
                        var tB = (tA[tA.length - 1] || [0, 0]);
                        tA.push([tS.values[0] + tB[0], tS.values[1] + tB[1]]);
                        break
                    case 'h':
                        var tB = (tA[tA.length - 1] || [0, 0]);
                        tA.push([tB[0] + tS.values[0], tB[1]]);
                        break
                    case 'v':
                        var tB = (tA[tA.length - 1] || [0, 0]);
                        tA.push([tB[0], tB[1] + tS.values[0]]);
                        break
                    case 'Z': case 'z':
                        tA.push(tA[0]);
                        break
                }
            }
        };

        return tA
    };
```

Regards, Ruedi

Comment: Do you mean you need a program to do it automatically?

Comment: @Paul LeBeau: A script, yes. Yet if I had a way/formula to do it manually I could turn it into a script myself. Sadly I have no idea how to find a pattern from a list of numbers.

Comment: How many different dash patterns are you likely to see?  Doing it manually is out of the question then?

Comment: [Does this question help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847164/how-to-find-repeating-sequence-of-integers-in-an-array-of-integers)

Comment: The SVG origins from a dwg conversion, so the amount of patterns varies by the architects mood. Sadly doing it manually is ouf of question in my case.